# Want to scrape table data without id and class using PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

This is the table I want to scrape data from it. I can scrape it using PHP dom but the problem is I only want to fetch dates without -- Vacent -- rows. I have tried from 4 days but no luck.

```
<table cellspacing="1" width="700px">
    <colgroup><col width="100px">
    <col width="100px">
    <col width="30px">
    <col width="30px">
    <col width="60px">
    <col width="40px">
    <col width="45px">

</colgroup><tbody><tr bgcolor="#d6d6d6">
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>In</th>
    <th>Out</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Adults</th>
    <th>Children</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
</tr>

<tr>

    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Nov Thu 23, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Nov Fri 24, 2017</td>
    <td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888; color: #3333ff; text-align: center">-- Vacant --</td>


</tr>


<tr>


    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Nov Fri 24, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Nov Mon 27, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">15:00&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">10:00&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">WILLIAMS, KEELY</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">4&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">0&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>


<tr>

    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Nov Mon 27, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Dec Thu 07, 2017</td>
    <td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888; color: #3333ff; text-align: center">-- Vacant --</td>


</tr>


<tr>


    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Dec Thu 07, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Dec Sun 10, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">15:00&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">10:00&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">HALL, TYLER</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">4&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">0&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>


<tr>

    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Dec Sun 10, 2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888">Dec Sat 16, 2017</td>
    <td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888; color: #3333ff; text-align: center">-- Vacant --</td>


</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I want to fetch only "From" and "To" fields values. but here no id or class so I used this method

```
$html = fetched HTML here;

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

    //get all the h2's with an id
    $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//table//td[@style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888"]');

    if($pokemon_row->length > 0){

        $oe = 1;
        foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
            if ($oe % 2 == 0) {
                //mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO booking VALUES('','','".(validateDate($row->nodeValue) ? $row->nodeValue : '')."')");
                echo (validateDate($row->nodeValue) && $row->nodeValue!='-- Vacant --' ? $row->nodeValue : '') . " | <br>";
            } else {
                //mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO booking VALUES('','".(validateDate($row->nodeValue) ? $row->nodeValue : '')."','')");
                echo (validateDate($row->nodeValue) && $row->nodeValue!='-- Vacant --' ? $row->nodeValue : '') . " , <br>";
            }

            $oe++;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'no html returend.';
}


// Check date validate function
function validateDate($date)
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('M D d, Y', $date);
    return $d && $d->format('M D d, Y') == $date;
}
```

The problem is I don't need "-- Vacant --" dates. 
I have tried this code but no luck.

can anybody please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using PHPQuery, it's much better then xPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortened this and rewrote it to use it in the cli, but those xpath queries worked for me:

```
$pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('//table//tr[not(contains(., \'-- Vacant --\'))]');

if($pokemon_row->length > 0) {
    $oe = 1;
    foreach($pokemon_row as $row) {
        $nodeList = $pokemon_xpath->query('td', $row);

        $fromNode = $nodeList->item(0);
        $toNode = $nodeList->item(1);

        echo 'From :'.(validateDate($fromNode->nodeValue) ? $fromNode->nodeValue : '') . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'To :'. (validateDate($toNode->nodeValue) ? $toNode->nodeValue : '') . PHP_EOL;

        $oe++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, man. It's working. can you little bit of explain me about ., \'-- Vacant --\' @Benjamin

Comment: That query is only looking for rows which do not contain the "-- Vacant --" string. After having those rows the script will only take the first (0) and the second (1) td element to get the dates you were looking for.